# Perl: is there something better than $var = $_;?

Tags: perl, variable-assignment

It is not important question and I know it, buuut `$var = $_;` looks just lame, is there better (shorter) way to make that assignment?

To clarify my question: I know I can use `$_` in code easily (thats why I like it), but sometimes I need to store `$_` and do something on `$_` and then get back old value of `$_` (for example).

Comment: So you want use your array/list to calculate something but don't want to modify it? Just copy the list up front then, or `use Storable 'clone';`

Comment: "do something" Such as what? How can you store it without using an assignment?

Comment: @TLP my question was _is there better (shorter) way to make that assignment?_ I want to store it. I'm asking about **shorter** way to assign `$_`.

Comment: You can use `map` to generate a new array by applying your `do_something` to an existing array: `my @squares = map { $_**2 } @old;`

Comment: @korda It looks like you are asking if there is a better or shorter way to write `$var = $_` (or get that functionality). To me, that is a rather strange request, because A) `$var = $_` is already about as short as it gets, and B) there is no *better* way to make that assignment than using the equal sign. You are probably thinking of something specific, which is why I asked for an example.

Comment: @TLP Thank you. That was **exactly** what I wanted to know. Only that. I know it may seem strange but one of reasons I like Perl is that you can write same code in many ways. I was using `$_` to make shorter programs and I was simply wondering if I can shorten assignment too. Post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the OPs request, I am posting my comment as an answer.

It looks like you are asking if there is a better or shorter way to write `$var = $_` (or get that functionality). To me, that is a rather strange request, because:

- `$var = $_` is already about as short as it gets, and
- there is no better way to make that assignment than using the equal
  sign.

Answer (score 8):

Within a new lexical scope, you can localise $_ which will prevent any modifications within that scope from affecting its value outside that scope.

An example is necessary for clarification:

```
$_ = 1;
say;
{ # open a new scope
    local $_ = 3;
    $_++;
    say;
} # close the scope
say;
```

This should print

```
1
4
1
```

I find it invaluable for writing functions which make extensive use of $_ internally, because I don't like it when they clobber $_ in their surrounding scope. However, you can also use it to 'set aside' a variable and work with a new version of it for a while.

Comment: interesting... However I would have to do `local $_ = $_` in my case. still not perfect.

Comment: if I want to store previous value of `$_` in new `local` version of `$_` I have to use `local $_ = $_` or there is a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: No that's the only way to do that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6):

In many circumstances it's unnecessary. For example:

```
foreach my $var (@array) {
  dostuff($var);
}
```

or

```
my $var;
while ($var = <>) {
  chomp($var);
  dostuff($var);
}
```

or

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  dostuff($_);
}
```

Comment: I know - but to be honest it doesn't answer my question. Also if I try to learn how to shorten that code even more I already know that kind of stuff ;)

Comment: I think you'll be sacrificing a lot of readability to save yourself just a few keystrokes. I know it's perl but there are limits outside of obfuscation contests.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want `$var = $_`?  Just use `$_` or pass it in as a parameter to the function, in the function call it `$var`.

Comment: The question is still invalid.  After you pass $_ to a function you don't get that functions $_ back, you retain your original $_ value.  If you want to capture what that function returned then put it into another scalar.

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point here. Look at the answer I accepted, it clarifies it better.

Comment: To be honest you are making mistake... often when you use some function in Perl result will be stored in $_ if you won't specify other variable... I like how I can make code in Perl that is striped from variables because I think it is _cool_. My question was really simple, I guess I just wasn't able to explain what I want well.

I don't really like your tone also. "you're trying to cut-n-paste code rather than understand it" - how you can tell that, do you know me? Did I put any code in question? It is rather rude to say something like that.

Answer (score 3):

All good answers. I'd like to contribute with one more example related to "just use `$_`" as @awm said.

10 minutes ago I just wrote these lines:

```
sub composite
{
   foreach my $element (@_)
   {
     # do something ...
   }
}

sub simple
{
  &composite( $_[ int rand @_ ] );
}
```

which is a *Perl Golf* ([cit.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123109/greg-bacon)) , not recommended to use at all.

If you need to store `$_` somewhere else and after some time use it's original value you should perform the assignment.

Comment: Try out some time what [perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic) has to say about your code.

Comment: @daxim I already know I'll change that lines, by the way you made me curious about how many severities it causes :)

Comment: @daxim I perlcritic-ed, it wasn't that bad... better than I expected, hehe. :P

Answer (score 3):

Use `local`:

```
$_ = 1;
{
    local $_ = 2;
    say;           # prints 2
}
say;               # prints 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the function commonly named `apply` is what you are looking for.  Apply is just like `map` except it makes a copy of its arguments first:

**`apply {CODE} LIST`**

```
apply a function that modifies $_ to a shallow copy of LIST and returns the copy

    print join ", " => apply {s/$/ one/} "this", "and that";
    > this one, and that one
```

Here's an implementation from one of my modules:

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Gen#apply

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to generate a new array by transforming an existing array:

```
my @squares = map { $_**2 } 1..10 ;         # 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100

my @after   = map { process($_) } @before ; # @before unchanged, @after created
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would like to access the pushdown stack of the `$_` local values. That *could* be cool. However, you can do *something* like this yourself. I can show you the basics.

```
our @A;           # declare a stack
*::A = *A{ARRAY}; # "Globalize" it if necessary.

sub pd (&;@) # <- block operator prototype indicating language sugar
{ 
    # I would have really preferred to do a push here.
    local @A = ( @A, $_ ); 
    # pull the block argument
    my $block = shift;
    # Ensure at least one execution
    @_ = $_ unless @_;
    # + Scalar behavior option #1
    # return $block->( local $_ = shift ) if not wantarray // 1; 
    # + Scalar behavior option #2
    # unless ( wantarray // 1 ) {
    #     my $result;
    #     while ( @_ ) { 
    #         local $_ = shift;
    #         return $result if defined( $result = $block->( $_ ));
    #     }
    #     return;
    # }
    # Standard filter logic
    return map { $block->( $_ ) } @_;
}
```

And here is a *simple* list comprehension based on this:

```
my @comp 
    = map { pd { pd { join '', @A[-2,-1], $_ } qw<g h> } qw<d e f>; } qw<a b c>
    ;
```

Here's `@comp`:

```
@comp: [
         'adg',
         'adh',
         'aeg',
         'aeh',
         'afg',
         'afh',
         'bdg',
         'bdh',
         'beg',
         'beh',
         'bfg',
         'bfh',
         'cdg',
         'cdh',
         'ceg',
         'ceh',
         'cfg',
         'cfh'
       ]
```